# Union RDDs after a loop PySpark

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm using PySpark and I'm looking for a way to modify 4 rdds, which are included in a list. When I display my list, I have something like this :

[image]

So given :

```
for r in repartionned_rdd:

    print r.collect()
```

Gives :

```
[(u'_guid_NCw7SuFnCh_mFW3SI3qTvBCbqXKD4mtsdJvWE7HNgNg=', (u'f', u'KSJakOd2|KtC9ZF9h'))]
[(u'_guid_OCs2au-sKnxzPE0uRPDP4hg1vvhgpzRAAYjNWRQpKbw=', (u'f', u'KxrylzuA|KpSXJwH2')), (u'_guid_txH15ULaeUDBC4Z_NlEOj2xoYBFa-08imqIBLfYsKps=', (u'f', u'bda54c71-cd1e-4eb7-856c-ba2e6def30c8|6e189e07-807e-41a2-a60a-b07d894a2905')), (u'_guid_ehCT6NyD9l3q3NV9ZroaWVEo3bnDt4tvbU_fMBrEn1g=', (u'm', u'537D69B4-743A-45B9-BED1-A25AA5926F13|2bb3e466-edc5-4302-b102-3bddb1f8c490|aa4760de-104c-4dc3-94c3-336427f89723')), (u'_guid_9F4Ph5GztLN9IlWNgZWKPMCcT4N3Je6-93iM_130F-c=', (u'f', u'KOQqBzhU|KrDt5GC4')), (u'_guid_nPlE_f-zoOHNYiXJSGXWoVryc1U4Bnfxkow3P0mDUFY=', (u'f', u'Kh3tIZR1|Khs0tRsh|K3geBqb_|KBrVNcDX|Jg2uDy8M|529816a3-ee43-4423-961f-8aedaf25d58c')), (u'331d8410d4924e72b0f0585e888c85ce', (u'f', u'1F37807A-CBEA-4B78-85D7-5A97B37B539E'))]
[(u'28b195c271f14a329235c262e7baecbf', (u'm', u'50c41480-a94e-4afa-a732-b6ed7a057239'))]
[(u'c65ac2064bc14116a363125392dcc6f7', (u'f', u'77e4b9b3-83b4-4553-b274-7a16f553cf05')), (u'171f92200d634d62bdc6685bdb7a94e3', (u'f', u'bdf53cb6-695d-4dde-b0c1-d1a34ebea6f7|a09e4074-c22e-48a1-9976-ee2151b5888c|K1Umlb5M|639B02B4-24AD-4069-99A2-C68E8C8F7F06|KjE3wXIr')), (u'_guid_wQZIzeFxciX9CIHUPeWOF2euOIC0jiOsXVXN98_zCh8=', (u'f', u'F0992237-2598-4B13-AA8A-C37D436B901C|C80D1A89-DD84-4734-838F-128F99EBDD20|KthpuVu0')), (u'_guid_ufOcKO48drwr50yJN26NriX5MLYONwmALxWcmly7oqQ=', (u'f', u'KlY10YxX|KyCVx_km'))]
```

My objectif is to add a kind of new "column" to every rdd in this list. This row will contains a unique index for every rdd. my code :

```
for i, rdd in enumerate(repartionned_rdd):

    new_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x : x + (float(i), ))

    print new_rdd.collect()
```

Which gives :

```
[(u'_guid_NCw7SuFnCh_mFW3SI3qTvBCbqXKD4mtsdJvWE7HNgNg=', 
 (u'f', u'KSJakOd2|KtC9ZF9h'), 0.0)]

[(u'_guid_OCs2au-sKnxzPE0uRPDP4hg1vvhgpzRAAYjNWRQpKbw=', 
 (u'f', u'KxrylzuA|KpSXJwH2'), 1.0), 
 (u'_guid_txH15ULaeUDBC4Z_NlEOj2xoYBFa-08imqIBLfYsKps=', 
 (u'f', u'bda54c71-cd1e-4eb7-856c-ba2e6def30c8|6e189e07-807e-41a2-a60a-b07d894a2905'), 1.0),
 (u'_guid_ehCT6NyD9l3q3NV9ZroaWVEo3bnDt4tvbU_fMBrEn1g=', 
 (u'm', u'537D69B4-743A-45B9-BED1-A25AA5926F13|2bb3e466-edc5-4302-b102-3bddb1f8c490|aa4760de-104c-4dc3-94c3-336427f89723'), 1.0), 
 (u'_guid_9F4Ph5GztLN9IlWNgZWKPMCcT4N3Je6-93iM_130F-c=', 
 (u'f', u'KOQqBzhU|KrDt5GC4'), 1.0), 
 (u'_guid_nPlE_f-zoOHNYiXJSGXWoVryc1U4Bnfxkow3P0mDUFY=', 
 (u'f', u'Kh3tIZR1|Khs0tRsh|K3geBqb_|KBrVNcDX|Jg2uDy8M|529816a3-ee43-4423-961f-8aedaf25d58c'), 1.0), 
 (u'331d8410d4924e72b0f0585e888c85ce', 
 (u'f', u'1F37807A-CBEA-4B78-85D7-5A97B37B539E'), 1.0)]

[(u'28b195c271f14a329235c262e7baecbf', 
 (u'm', u'50c41480-a94e-4afa-a732-b6ed7a057239'), 2.0)]

[(u'c65ac2064bc14116a363125392dcc6f7', 
 (u'f', u'77e4b9b3-83b4-4553-b274-7a16f553cf05'), 3.0), 
 (u'171f92200d634d62bdc6685bdb7a94e3', 
 (u'f', u'bdf53cb6-695d-4dde-b0c1-d1a34ebea6f7|a09e4074-c22e-48a1-9976-ee2151b5888c|K1Umlb5M|639B02B4-24AD-4069-99A2-C68E8C8F7F06|KjE3wXIr'), 3.0),
 (u'_guid_wQZIzeFxciX9CIHUPeWOF2euOIC0jiOsXVXN98_zCh8=', 
 (u'f', u'F0992237-2598-4B13-AA8A-C37D436B901C|C80D1A89-DD84-4734-838F-128F99EBDD20|KthpuVu0'), 3.0),
 (u'_guid_ufOcKO48drwr50yJN26NriX5MLYONwmALxWcmly7oqQ=', 
 (u'f', u'KlY10YxX|KyCVx_km'), 3.0)]
```

So every row in my new_rdd contains a new columns, which is concretely the rdd's index (as mentioned in the code!)

My objectif now is just to put all those new rdds in one unique rdd.
I tried this :

```
all_rdds_list =[]

for i, rdd in enumerate(repartionned_rdd):

    new_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x : x + (float(i), ))

    all_rdds_list.append(new_rdd)
```

But when I tried to display my rdds, I got this :

```
for x in all_rdds_list:

    print x.collect()
```

Result :

```
[(u'_guid_NCw7SuFnCh_mFW3SI3qTvBCbqXKD4mtsdJvWE7HNgNg=', 
 (u'f', u'KSJakOd2|KtC9ZF9h'), 3.0)]

[(u'_guid_OCs2au-sKnxzPE0uRPDP4hg1vvhgpzRAAYjNWRQpKbw=', 
 (u'f', u'KxrylzuA|KpSXJwH2'), 3.0), 
 (u'_guid_txH15ULaeUDBC4Z_NlEOj2xoYBFa-08imqIBLfYsKps=', 
 (u'f', u'bda54c71-cd1e-4eb7-856c-ba2e6def30c8|6e189e07-807e-41a2-a60a-b07d894a2905'), 3.0),
 (u'_guid_ehCT6NyD9l3q3NV9ZroaWVEo3bnDt4tvbU_fMBrEn1g=', 
 (u'm', u'537D69B4-743A-45B9-BED1-A25AA5926F13|2bb3e466-edc5-4302-b102-3bddb1f8c490|aa4760de-104c-4dc3-94c3-336427f89723'), 3.0), 
 (u'_guid_9F4Ph5GztLN9IlWNgZWKPMCcT4N3Je6-93iM_130F-c=', 
 (u'f', u'KOQqBzhU|KrDt5GC4'), 3.0), 
 (u'_guid_nPlE_f-zoOHNYiXJSGXWoVryc1U4Bnfxkow3P0mDUFY=', 
 (u'f', u'Kh3tIZR1|Khs0tRsh|K3geBqb_|KBrVNcDX|Jg2uDy8M|529816a3-ee43-4423-961f-8aedaf25d58c'), 3.0), 
 (u'331d8410d4924e72b0f0585e888c85ce', 
 (u'f', u'1F37807A-CBEA-4B78-85D7-5A97B37B539E'), 3.0)]

[(u'28b195c271f14a329235c262e7baecbf', 
 (u'm', u'50c41480-a94e-4afa-a732-b6ed7a057239'), 3.0)]

[(u'c65ac2064bc14116a363125392dcc6f7', 
 (u'f', u'77e4b9b3-83b4-4553-b274-7a16f553cf05'), 3.0), 
 (u'171f92200d634d62bdc6685bdb7a94e3', 
 (u'f', u'bdf53cb6-695d-4dde-b0c1-d1a34ebea6f7|a09e4074-c22e-48a1-9976-ee2151b5888c|K1Umlb5M|639B02B4-24AD-4069-99A2-C68E8C8F7F06|KjE3wXIr'), 3.0),
 (u'_guid_wQZIzeFxciX9CIHUPeWOF2euOIC0jiOsXVXN98_zCh8=', 
 (u'f', u'F0992237-2598-4B13-AA8A-C37D436B901C|C80D1A89-DD84-4734-838F-128F99EBDD20|KthpuVu0'), 3.0),
 (u'_guid_ufOcKO48drwr50yJN26NriX5MLYONwmALxWcmly7oqQ=', 
 (u'f', u'KlY10YxX|KyCVx_km'), 3.0)]
```

Help ? thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this :

```
def get_population_id(repartionned_rdd):

    idx = range(len(repartionned_rdd))

    FullRDD = sc.emptyRDD()

    for (i, rdd) in zip(idx, repartionned_rdd):

        FullRDD = FullRDD.union(rdd.map(lambda x: x + (float(i),)))

    return FullRDD
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your approach. First you use a variable which changes before the method assignment is evaluated. The map calls are transformations and thus only execute when you apply an action (like `collect`). This is why when you collect inside the enumerate loop you see the correct additional column, but in your later example it chooses the last value of `i` for each mapping.

The second issue is that if you're trying to union rdds together you should use the `union` function rather than a list of rdds. If you actually wanted a list of rdds, then you can replace the union below with the list append you had before.

```
full_rdd = None
for i, rdd in enumerate(repartionned_rdd):
    new_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x : x + (float(i),))
    if full_rdd is None:
        full_rdd = new_rdd
    else:
        full_rdd = sc.union([full_rdd, new_rdd])
    # This will force the lazy evaluation to execute now before `i` changes
    full_rdd.count()
```

Comment: Pyrce : Thank you, but applying your code, I got this error message : **TypeError: union() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)**

Comment: @DataAddicted opps, I missed the listification around the RDD arguments. Should be correct now.